# Regular Expression Password Validation

Tags: regex, pcre, assertion

I'd like to use regular expression to validate the characters requirement of a password.

Requirement:
Password should have 16 characters.

1. Character 1-4 should have at least 1 digit.
2. Character 5-8 should have at least 1 lower case character.
3. Character 9-12 should have at least 1 upper case character.
4. Character 13-16 should have at least 1 symbol (punctuation).

I've tried to use regular expression with a positive lookahead but it does not work finally:

`echo 'XXXX9999ccccXXX%' | grep -P '^((?=.*[0-9]).{4})((?=.*[a-z]).{4})((?=.*[A-Z]).{4})((?=.*\pP).{4})$'`

Answer (score 4):

Your lookahead syntax is off, because it is not correctly checking the positions you mentioned in your requirements.  The following regex pattern seems to work for me:

```
^(?=.{0,3}\d)(?=.{4,7}[a-z])(?=.{8,11}[A-Z])(?=.{12,15}[.,$%^&!@]).{16}$
```

Explanation:

```
(?=.{0,3}\d)           - number in positions 1-4
(?=.{4,7}[a-z])        - lowercase in positions 5-8
(?=.{8,11}[A-Z])       - uppercase in positions 9-12
(?=.{12,15}[.,$%^&!@]) - symbol in positions 13-16
```

### Demo

I don't know `grep` or Linux well enough to comment on whether you are making best use, but this should at least fix any problems you were having with the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?=.{0,3}\d).{4}(?=.{0,3}[a-z]).{4}(?=.{0,3}[A-Z]).{4}(?=.{0,3}[\W_]).{4}$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/n2AmRN/1)

Basically, the pattern comprises four lookahead-consuming pattern parts, and since each consuming pattern matches 4 chars, in total, it matches string of 16 chars (note that `^` and `$` anchors are also important).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{0,3}\d)` - there must be a digit after 0 to 3 chars
- `.{4}` - any 4 chars are consumed
- `(?=.{0,3}[a-z])` - there must be a lowercase letter after 0 to 3 chars
- `.{4}` - any 4 chars are consumed
- `(?=.{0,3}[A-Z])` - there must be an uppercase letter after 0 to 3 chars
- `.{4}` - any 4 chars are consumed
- `(?=.{0,3}[\W_]).{4}` - there must be a special char (non-alphanumeric) after 0 to 3 chars
- `$` - end of string